# After update - buildings are half gone

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My kids logged into one of their favorite PE worlds only to discover that entire sections of their buildings and creations are just *missing* it's not just one or two, it's EVERY building in their worlds. Can I do something about that for them?

ipad edition.

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems the worlds were either updated or corrupted, there is really nothing you can do since it is mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You could try restoring from iCloud back-up. iCloud will let you choose multiple restore points.
Make sure iCloud back-up is "on", then wipe/reset the device and restore from iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the world is most likely corrupted.